# Android emulator does not start ubuntu 22.04.3

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-emulator

I'm trying to run my android application in my emulator and it does not start, it simply does nothing. I have also been running it from the terminal and it shows the following message:

```
INFO    | Android emulator version 32.1.15.0 (build_id 10696886) (CL:N/A)

INFO    | Found systemPath /home/MYUSER/Android/Sdk/system-images/android-29/google_apis_playstore/x86/

INFO    | Storing crashdata in: /tmp/android-MYUSER/emu-crash.db, detection is enabled

INFO    | Duplicate loglines will be removed, if you wish to see each indiviudal line launch with the -log-nofilter flag.

WARNING | Failed to process .ini file /home/MYUSER/.android/avd/API29.avd/quickbootChoice.ini for reading.

WARNING | cannot add library /home/MYUSER/Android/Sdk/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.so: failed

INFO    | added library /home/MYUSER/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.so
qemu-system-x86_64: -drive if=none,index=0,id=system,if=none,file=/home/MYUSER/Android/Sdk/system-images/android-29/google_apis_playstore/x86//system.img,read-only: Could not open '/home/MYUSER/Android/Sdk/system-images/android-29/google_apis_playstore/x86//system.img': Operation not permitted
```

What I see is that qemu-system starts, sometimes the window with the emulator appears but is full black and doesn´t respond.

[image]

My laptop specs are:

Intel® Core™ i7-11850H

RAM 32GB

Graphics: NVIDIA RTX A2000

Ubuntu version: Ubuntu 22.04.3

Comment: Does the path mentioned in the last log line exists?

Comment: system.img ? Yes it does

Comment: @Robert At the the problem was the anti virus from the company, nothing related with drivers or configuration errors in the SO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the antivirus software from the company, nothing related with drivers or SO configurations